# Splitting in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I want to be able to split some text out of a txtfile:
For example:

```
Brackets#Release 1.11.6#Path-to-Brackets
Atom#v1.4#Path-to-Atom
```

I just want to have the **"Release 1.11.6"** part. I am doing a where-object starts with Brackets but I don't know the full syntax. Here is my code:

```
 "Get-Content -Path thisfile.txt | Where-Object{$_ < IM STUCK HERE > !
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
((Get-Content thisfile.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match '^Brackets' }) -Split '#')[1]
```

This uses the `-match` operator to filter out any lines that don't start with Brackets (the `^` special regex character indicates that what follows must be at the beginning of the line). Then it uses the `-Split` operator to split those lines on `#` and then it uses the array index `[1]` to get the second element of the split (arrays start at 0).

Note that this will throw an error if the split on # doesn't return at least two elements and it assumes that the text you want is always the second of those elements.

Comment: This should work for sure and thank you so much! The only problem is, when I compare it to a fileversion, it has whitelines before and after which makes it not "match"

Comment: There's an operator called trim that removes leading and trailing spaces, perhaps that will help. It's hard to give specific advice without knowing more about your issue. It possibly warrants a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bracketsRelease = Get-Content -path thisfile.txt | foreach-object {

    if ( $_ -match 'Brackets#(Release [^#]+)#' )
    {
        $Matches[1]
    }

}
```

or

```
(select-string -Path file.txt -Pattern 'Brackets#(Release [^#]+)#').Matches[0].Groups[1].value
```